# React hooks useState to set multiple states in context provider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a `createContext` component that is using `useState` to set multiple values returned from a `fetch` function. However in my code below, when a state is updated, the others states return to the original value.

For example, in `getCountryCode()` the state is updated for `countryCode`, but then `iconCode` in `weatherInit()` fetches its value and `countryCode` returns to the original `US`.

```
import React, { createContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const GlobalConsumer = createContext();

export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    menuPanel: false,
    countryCode: 'US',
    weatherLoading: true,
    iconCode: '',
    fahrenheit: '',
    celcius: '',
    showCelcius: false
  });

  const getCountryCode = () => {
    const url = `https://ipapi.co/json/`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        const countryCode = data.country;
        setState({ ...state, countryCode });
      });
  };

  const weatherInit = () => {
    const CITY_LAT = '...';
    const CITY_LON = '...';
    const OW_KEY = '...';
    const url = `//api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=${CITY_LAT}&lon=${CITY_LON}&units=imperial&appid=${OW_KEY}`;
    fetch(url)
      .then(data => data.json())
      .then(data => {
        const iconCode = data.weather[0].id;
        setState({ ...state, iconCode });
        const fahrenheit = Math.round(data.main.temp_max);
        setState({ ...state, fahrenheit });
        const celcius = Math.round((5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32.0));
        setState({ ...state, celcius });
        setTimeout(() => {
          setState({ ...state, weatherLoading: false });
        }, 150);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getCountryCode();
    weatherInit();
  }, []);

  return (
    <GlobalConsumer.Provider
      value={{
        contextData: state,
        togglemMenuPanel: () => {
          setState({ ...state, menuPanel: !state.menuPanel });
        },
        toggleCelcius: () => {
          setState({ ...state, showCelcius: !state.showCelcius });
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalConsumer.Provider>
  );
};
```

I believe that this is caused because each `value` requires it's own `useState`. However, can these values be merged or is there another way to achieve this outcome, where I am only required to pass as `data` to the *Provider context*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you are using the old value of `state` when calling `setState()`. As documented [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) (Scroll down to the "Note"-block) you have to pass a function to your `setState` call:

```js
const iconCode = data.weather[0].id;
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, iconCode }));
const fahrenheit = Math.round(data.main.temp_max);
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, fahrenheit }));
const celcius = Math.round((5.0 / 9.0) * (fahrenheit - 32.0));
setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, celcius }));
setTimeout(() => {
  setState(prevState => ({ ...prevState, weatherLoading: false }));
}, 150);
```

> Unlike the setState method found in class components, useState does not automatically merge update objects. You can replicate this behavior by combining the function updater form with object spread syntax:

```
setState(prevState => {
  // Object.assign would also work
  return {...prevState, ...updatedValues};
});
```